# Application exits on back button pressed from sub activity

Tags: android

the application exits when I press back button from child activity.

The below is event will triggered when I press the button in the main activity.

```
 public void GoToMember(View view)
 {
   Intent indent = new Intent(this,MemberActivity.class);
   startActivity(indent);
 }
```

Please let me know what i am missing in main or child activity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the full code....

Comment: Also, what do your logs say when this happens? Post the errors in your logs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onBackPressed in your child activity and call finish() before the super call.

```
@Override
protected void onBackPressed() {

super.onBackPressed();
finish();

}
```